# Как решать проблему с ошибкой internal error parsing svg при попытке вставить картинку в drawable директорию android?

Tags: android

Проблема довольно популярная и у каждого android-разработчика наверняка возникала - нежелание Android Studio вставить понравившуюся картинку svg формата. Возникает ошибка `internal error parsing svg`. Многие предлагают способы которые у них работали и им помогли, вот например я нашел [такую](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895280/internal-error-parsing-svg-file-in-android-studio) ссылку. Вроде-бы как в ответе все расписано и я проверил - все работает. НО, может есть какой-то нормальный инструмент или сервис для "ремонта" битых иконок и картинок, ведь каждую картинку в маленьком проекте можно просмотреть, но когда в проекте несколько десятков или даже сотен картинок, то задолбешься их все переправлять. Пробовал я разные сервисы, [типа](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) такого. Он вроде как много чего "допиливает" в картинке, но как результат - картинка упорно не хочет вставляться в студии.

Может у кого-то были подобные ситуации и есть более стабильное и эффективное решение?